# Any issues with ip leaking when using youtube-dl with tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, anonymity, ubuntu, ip-address

I've wondering if using youtube-dl to download youtube videos will leak my real ip, like with p2p. If so, is there a way to protect against this, or is there another linux app that can do the same thing without ip leakage?

Comment: Youtube-dl should use the proxy you set it to for getting the download url as well as the real download.